# Unity Social API

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, game-center, google-play-games

We are writing an application in Unity3D for both iOS and Android and we'd like to use the provided Social API to retrive and post the highScores on iOS (using GameCenter) and Android (using Google Play Game Services).

To keep the application simple, its weight low and to avoid cross-compilation extra setups we'd prefer not to use external plugins (unless point 4 is true).

I googled around for documentation and tutorials and I found [THIS ONE](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/tutorial-gamecenter-leaderboards-in-5-minutes-for-intermediate-advanced-scripters.238824/).
The implementation has been done in C#, but since the Unity guide also provides a c# version it went all straight forward.

However we couldn't manage to get this work, probably also because we don't understand well how this API really work.

First of all: the Unity guide states that "It [the api] provides a unified interface to different social back-ends, such as XBox Live or GameCenter", but in the implementation is not specified which social back-end is being used. How unity knows that? It switches depending on the platform?

Second: I understood in various guides that the GUI provided to show the leaderboard is directly provided by the host platform and from the console log i get these following success messages:

```
Authenticated, checking achievements

Error: no achievements found

Successfully reported achievement progress
```

but running the application in the editor, in a build made for windows or an apk used in BlueStacks, i get the same message when I call the function Social.ShowLeaderboardUI(); which is

```
ShowLeaderboardUI not implemented
```

I could expect it from the editor and the exe, but BlueStack emulates Android and i would be surprised if it doesn't provide the google play services. However i also read about a "sandbox mode" which is the one that should run in the editor and this leads to point three:

I can't find a way to set this sandbox mode, at least not from that guide.

Fourth point: Unity has a GameCenter class, but no classes for the Google Play Games Services, so: I can do what I want with iOS but I need an external plugin which implements the ISocial interface for Android?

Fifth point: How do i handle authentication in both sandbox and deploy mode?

As you can see I'm surely missing something on the coding side, conceptual side or both. Can you provide a step-by-step procedure on how to achieve what i need? I don't need to get pieces of source code, but if someone can explain me well how this API works it would be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For **Android**:

To integrate Google Play Service into Unity, you need to use a plugin. You can find the Google supported plugin [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity). You can find information on how leaderboards work [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards). Essentially how it works is:

1. You create the leaderboard in the [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/)
2. You submit scores to the leaderboard created (at whenever you determin is the appropriate time)
3. Google Play Services sends a response back telling if it's a high score  or not.

I suggest you take a look at the [Cubic Pilot_4.6](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/tree/master/samples/CubicPilot_4.6) sample as that demonstrates how to implement leaderboards. Also, you really ought to test this on a physical device, due to how emulators may have trouble handling Google Play Services and account logins.

As far as authentication goes, Google Play Services takes care of most of it for you. You can probably see more in the samples (`Social.localUser.Authenticate`).

Comment: Many thanks, I'll try everything you suggested tomorrow. While for GameCenter on iOS can you confirm that I already have everything I need on Unity just using the GameCenterPlatform class?

Comment: Also, you might want to evaluate if using Google Play Game Services on iOS would suite your needs as well, it has the added benefit of sharing leaderboards and multiplayer instances across iOS and Android.

Comment: That would be nice, but unfortunately I'm not the one in charge for that decision, we have been asked explicitly to use GameCenter on iOS

Comment: @MastErAldo I'm not as familiar with iOS, but I _believe_ that you don't need any plugins or the like and Unity has everything you need. The docs [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Social.html) say **by default GameCenter is used on iOS**.

Comment: I can confirm that the GooglePlay plugin worked like a charm even on BlueStacks. 

Just one note: the notes on the project's page aren't really exaustive to make it work, I followed this tutorial: 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FuOJLPezLU8

to set up everything correctly. One more note: the developer in the video forgets to mention about this line of code:

PlayGamesPlatform.Activate() 

which is the first method that needs to be called, even before Authenticate()

Answer (score 0):

Current implementation does only provide implementation for GameCenter and XboxLive. There's a property [Social.Active](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Social.Active.html) which can be used to modify what social platform is used. You can set a object which implements [ISocialPlatform](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SocialPlatforms.ISocialPlatform.html) but im not sure if that interface is fully open - thus, im not sure if anyone can implement that..